# oracle insert into column using subquery

Tags: oracle, insert, subquery

I want to insert data into a column in the table.

```
Table a
ID  col1  col2
1    A    null  
2    B    null

Table b
ID  col1 
1    C
2    D
```

Expected results:

```
Table A
ID   col1  col2
1     A     C
2     B     D
```

I tried this:

```
insert into tableA (col2) 
select b.col1
from tableB b , tableA a
where b.id = a.id
```

and I received

```
0 row inserted.
```

How do I insert the col1 in B into col2 in A for the matching 'id' columns?

Thank you.

Comment: What you need to do is UPDATE, not INSERT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use Merge statement when inserting based on joins.
Also in table tableA col2 already exist but you want to insert a value on join then you must update that column.

merge into tablea a
     using tableb b
        on (b.id = a.id)
when matched
then
   update set a.col2 = b.col1;

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do shouldn't require a subquery. I'm not a huge fan of the `table a, table b` notation, try this:

```
update a
set col2 = b.col1
from tableB b 
join tableA a
on a.id = b.id
```